# HeadlessChrome Karma test - Cannot read property 'innerText' of null

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

My test for the component below keeps failing with the error message:

```
HeadlessChrome 78.0.3882 (Windows 10.0.0) LoginButtonGroupComponent : should have option to sign in with Google FAILED
    Failed: Cannot read property 'innerText' of null
```

However it passes for the `should have option to sign in with email address` test. Any idea what is wrong?

**Test**

```
import { LoginButtonGroupComponent } from './login-button-group.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { async, inject, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { TestStore } from '../../../core/core.spec';
import { State } from '../../../core/store/auth/auth.reducer';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';

describe('LoginButtonGroupComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
      imports: [FormsModule],
      providers: [
        { provide: Store, useClass: TestStore }
      ],
      declarations: [LoginButtonGroupComponent]
    }).compileComponents().then(() => {
    });
  }));
  describe(':', () => {
    let fixture, app;
    let store: TestStore<State>;

    beforeEach((inject([Store], (testStore: TestStore<State>) => {
      store = testStore;
      store.setState({user: null, error: null});
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginButtonGroupComponent);
      app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    })));

    afterEach(() => {
      fixture.destroy();
      app = null;
    });

    it('should create the component', async(() => {
      expect(app).toBeTruthy();
    }));

    it('should have option to sign in with Google', async(() => {
      expect(document.getElementById('googleSignIn').innerText.trim()).toBe('Sign in with Google');
    }));

    it('should have option to sign in with Facebook', async(() => {
      expect(document.getElementById('facebookSignIn').innerText.trim()).toBe('Sign in with Facebook');
    }));

    it('should have option to sign in with email address', async(() => {
      expect(document.getElementById('emailSignIn').innerText.trim()).toBe('or use your email address');
    }));
  });
});
```

**Component**

```
<p [ngClass]="setButtonAlignment(position)">
  <button (click)="googleSignIn()" *ngIf="!(isMobile | async)?.matches" class="btn btn-label btn-google"
          type="button">
    <label id="googleSignIn">
      <fa-icon [icon]="['fab', 'google']" size="xs"></fa-icon>
    </label> Sign in with Google
  </button>
  <button (click)="mobileGoogleSignIn()" *ngIf="(isMobile | async)?.matches" class="btn btn-label btn-google"
          type="button">
    <label id="mobileGoogleSignIn">
      <fa-icon [icon]="['fab', 'google']" size="xs"></fa-icon>
    </label> Sign in with Google
  </button>
  <button (click)="facebookSignIn()" *ngIf="!(isMobile | async)?.matches" class="btn btn-label btn-facebook"
          type="button">
    <label id="facebookSignIn">
      <fa-icon [icon]="['fab', 'facebook-f']" size="xs"></fa-icon>
    </label> Sign in with Facebook
  </button>
  <button (click)="mobileFacebookSignIn()" *ngIf="(isMobile | async)?.matches" class="btn btn-label btn-facebook"
          type="button">
    <label id="mobileFacebookSignIn">
      <fa-icon [icon]="['fab', 'facebook-f']" size="xs"></fa-icon>
    </label> Sign in with Facebook
  </button>
</p>
<p [ngClass]="setButtonAlignment(position)">
  <small>
    <a class="text-muted small-2" id="emailSignIn" routerLink="/register">or use your email address&nbsp;&nbsp;<fa-icon
      [icon]="['fas', 'long-arrow-alt-right']" size="xs"></fa-icon>
    </a>
  </small>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this button doesn't exist in a moment when this test run's because you render it with *async* pipe.
Try to use **detectChanges()**, maybe this will help you:

```js
 it('should have option to sign in with Facebook', async(() => {
   component = fixture.componentInstance;
   component.ngOnInit();
   fixture.detectChanges();
 expect(document.getElementById('facebookSignIn').innerText.trim()).toBe('Sign in with Facebook');
 }));
```

I really wonder why it not working for you. I have tried to simulate a similar situation and everything works fine.

```js
export interface IsMobile {
  matches: string;
}

export class UserProfileComponent implements OnInit {
  isMobile: Observable<IsMobile>;
  breikPoint = new BehaviorSubject<IsMobile>(null);

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.isMobile = this.breikPoint.asObservable();
  }

  changeView() {
    // simulate change the view
    this.breikPoint.next({matches: '320'});
  }
}
```

```html
 <button id="facebook" (click)="changeView()" *ngIf="!(isMobile | async)?.matches">Click</button>
```

```
 it('should display button and hide after ckick', async(() => {
component = fixture.componentInstance;
component.ngOnInit();
fixture.detectChanges();
const button = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#facebook'));
expect(button.nativeElement.innerText).toEqual('Click');

button.triggerEventHandler('click', null);
fixture.detectChanges();
const buttonAfterClick = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#facebook'));
expect(buttonAfterClick).toEqual(null);}));
```

Comment: Thanks. Sadly, this doesn't work. I get the same error message.

Comment: Maybe, the problem goes from the selector. You can try to get an element in another way:
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#facebookSignIn'));
    expect(de.nativeElement.innerText).toEqual('sds');

Comment: How so? I have set the id and text correctly in the component

Comment: Is it because of *ngIf? How do I set isMobile to false

Comment: isMobile - get's asynchronously via the async pipe, so when the test runs this value not initialized. You have to try to select this when the component is rendered. For me detectChanges() works. You can also try:   

fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
fixture.detectChanges();
expect().toBe()
})

Comment: The code for LoginButtonGroupComponent is here https://pastebin.com/2S4u2hsH

Comment: You initialize isMobile variable in ngOnInit lifecycle hook, so you can try to trigger this before checking. I had changed the first snippet according to to this

Comment: Where do I initialise `component`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210526/discussion-between-volodymyr-and-methuselah).